# Can I host a RAP application (Rich Ajax Platform) in Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm thinking of creating an application (RAP). I would like to know if I can host in Heroku or if you know a hosting provider that offers this service.

Comment: hold ya head dog, someone gon answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host anything that can run on Linux as long as you're not having to persist anything on the [filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) and you have a [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) which suits your needs.

Once those are in place, the world is your oyster.